# Asp.net charts automatically saved in C:\

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

My Charts in asp.net sometimes saved in `C:\`. Why that problem occurs? I did not write coding for exporting charts into anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Default path for the chart is pointed to directory c:

So try to change the default path.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" ImageLocation="your prefered location"
in the asp:chart control